# Let $1 + 2^m = 3^n$. What the max value of $(m+n)$?

Tags: proof-writing, problem-solving, integers

How do I determine the maximum value of $(m+n)$ if $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers if $1 + 2^m = 3^n$ holds? I have got $\text {max} (m+n)$ to be $5$ so far, but I do not know how to determine whether there is a larger possible sum. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: HINT: Write $3^n-1=2^m$ and try to factorize $3^n-1$ in order to show that there are no other solutions..

Comment: @Crostul: I thought that was still an open question...

Comment: @Crostul How straightforward is it to determine when $3^{n-1} + ... + 3 + 1$ is a power of 2? If n = 2 it is.  If n > 2, ... is it obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that there are no bigger solutions, suppose that $m\ge 2$. Then $3^n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and therefore $n$ must be even, say $n=2k$. We then have
$$2^m=(3^k-1)(3^k+1).$$
Thus $3^k-1$ and $3^k+1$ are powers of $2$. The only two powers of $2$ that differ by $2$ are $2$ and $4$. It follows that $3^k-1=2$, and therefore $k=1$.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer Nicolas. I understand every part of the solution, except for $n=2k$ part. Why must $n$ be even for $3^n - 1 $ to be a multiple of $4$? Is there a proof for this?

Comment: Because $3\equiv -1\mod 4$, hence $3^n\equiv (-1)^n$.

Comment: $2^m = 3^n - 1$.  If $m \ge 2$ then $4|2^m = 3^n - 1$ so $3^n = 1\mod 4$ but $3 = -1 \mod 4$ so $(-1)^n = 1 mod 4$.  If $n$ is odd $(-1)^n = -1 \ne 1 \mod 4$.  So $n$ is even.  So ...

Comment: If i was assigned this question for a maths exercise, would handing in this solution count as plagiarism? Or does this answer count as helping me to answer the question, rather than just a solution which I am copying? Because plagiarism is pretty much misrepresenting my potential, right? The difference is really fuzzy here.

Comment: I left little gaps that you can fill in.  That will make the solution more yours. Two gaps, why we can take $m\ge 2$, and then the can't be a square if $n$ is odd. And of course the only two powers of $2$ that differ by $2$ are $2$ and $4$.

Comment: Thanks Andre. @fleablood :I have been trying to follow your reasoning but don't understand this part: so $3^n=1 mod 4$ but $3=−1 mod 4$ so $(−1)^n=1 mod 4$ did you mean $\equiv$ instead of $=$ ?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $3^n\equiv (-1)^n\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. In particular, $3^n\not\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: I definately meant equiv.  I get lax in my Latex in comments.   I can't help you with plagerism.  If this is only homework I wouldn't worry about it.  If the professors singles you out and offers you a solar ship on this I'd admit I had help.  Don't copy.  Rewrite and try to put in your own words.  Research isn't plagerism even if it gets you the answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Out of curiosity, would the strategy used in solving this problem merely be manipulating the given equation until it is in a form which is useful to me? I just want to know the underlying technique so that I can apply it for myself in the future, rather than relying heavily on help from others. I feel like that would be a better way to get better at problem solving.

Comment: Diophantine equations are (provably!) difficult. One can try to exploit congruences, which I did in concluding that $n$ is even. But the similar problem involving $x^m-y^n=1$ (Catalan Conjecture) remained unsolved until fairly recently. One accumulates a set of tools, but all too often they are not enough.